Derivative of matrix to power between 0 and 1
Given a hermitian matrix $A(\lambda)$ that depends on some parameters $\lambda$, I need to calculate the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} A(\lambda)^s \;,
$$
where $0\leq s\leq 1$.
I know how the derivative of $A(\lambda)$ with respect to $\lambda$ looks like, so an answer involving such terms would be ok.
So far, I tried various ways to compute it, including $0 = \partial 1 /\partial \lambda = \partial (A^s A^{-s})/\partial \lambda$ or $\partial A/\partial \lambda = \partial (A^s A^{(1-s)})/\partial \lambda$ (and some more similar things), but nothing seems to work in the sense that I can only reduce it to the case of a derivative of the matrix $A$ to some other power, which does not simplify my problem.
Is there a nice way to calculate such derivatives in general? I heard that maybe Frechet derivatives may help?
Any help much appreciated.

I do not know of a general method, but $A(\lambda) = U(\lambda) D(\lambda) U(\lambda)^\dagger$ is diagonizable. If you can compute the individual matrices, then you can use that the fact that $A(\lambda)^s = U(\lambda) D(\lambda)^s U(\lambda)^\dagger$ and ordinary product rule to compute $\partial / \partial \lambda A(\lambda)$.

Thanks for the advice. The problem is that in general I do not know $U(\lambda)$ and $D(\lambda)$ because $A(\lambda)$ depends on the $\lambda$-parameters in a complicated way.

Are we given that $A(\lambda)$ is positive semidefinite?

I suspect the easiest approach might be to write
$$
A(\lambda)^s = \exp(s\log(A(\lambda)),
$$
and use the properties of the matrix logarithm and matrix exponential. That said, the derivatives of the logarithm and exponential in this context are fairly complicated.

@BenGrossmann: yes, $A(\lambda)$ can be assumed to be positive semidefinite. And thanks for the help, I will try to solve it using the matrix exponential and logarithm.

Note, however, that the logarithm will only be defined if $A(\lambda)$ is strictly positive definite, i.e. invertible. Things get even tricker if we can't make that assumption
